# Stream a TypedQuery in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `javax.persistence.TypedQuery` that I would like to stream. Here is my attempt:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(TypedQuery<T> query, int batchSize) {
    Query<T> convertedQuery = (Query<T>) query;
    convertedQuery.setFetchSize(batchSize);
    return convertedQuery.stream();
}
```

However if `<T>` is a Tuple, I get the following when I evaluated the stream (e.g. `.forEach()`):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Tuple
```

Presumably its coming through an Object array, however how do I make this generic so that the type doesn't matter?

Comment: What's with the `Query<T> convertedQuery = (Query<T>) query;`?

Comment: @Kayaman - that's the crux of my question - how do I get access to the `.stream()` method? It's isn't on `javax.persistence.TypedQuery`

Comment: Ah, you mean `org.hibernate.Query`.

Comment: I have the same problem, seems like the new `org.hibernate.query.Query.stream()` method does not map rows to `Tuple`s. It does not even map to `Object[]`: if you stream a `Query<Object[]>` you get a stream of `Object[][]` where every element is a an array with the row-mapped `Object[]` at index `0`.

Comment: I just had the same problem. I think this is a bug in Hibernate ORM 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Hibernate ORM that will be fixed with Hibernate ORM 5.2.11. See the bug report here:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11743